# Is that a way to declare a variable or it just a label (Nasm)?

Tags: variables, assembly, memory, nasm

As I know, when I want to reserve a memory (variable) I do the following:

```
msg db 'Hello world!',0
num db 10
```

But what about this:

```
str: db "Welcome to my OS", 0
```

My code (Very simple bootloader):

```
org 0x7c00
mov bp, 0x7c00
mov sp, bp 

mov ax, str
call printString

jmp $

printString:
    mov al, [str]
    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h
  
str db 'W', 0 ; <-- str must to be str:

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

`:` **is also used to declare variables or that is just a label?**

because I use this way `str:` to reserve memory in bios mode.

Comment: `msg`, `num` and `str` are all labels. I believe NASM allows you to omit the `:` in some cases.

Comment: NASM doesn't have a concept of "variables", it just emits bytes (in progbits sections) or reserves space (in nobits sections) and allows to place labels anywhere between.

Comment: The confusion about `str` is that it is also an x86 instruction. Try using another label that isn't a known instruction.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: You are right, the problem was as you mentioned. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rudiment of a MASM/TASM feature which doesn't exist in NASM.  The rudiment is that you can leave out the colon after a label name when using certain directives.

In MASM/TASM there used to be a difference between placing the colon and not placing it, but no such difference exists in NASM.

Comment: When leaving out the colon `:` in my case this error appears "error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand".
So, this way `msg db 'Hello world!',0` doesn't work with me instead `msg: db 'Hello world!',0` is working.

Comment: @Lion King: That shouldn't happen. Please show your full source text (preferably in a question).

Comment: @LionKing The colon which follows symbol definition helps NASM to distinguish whether the identifier is a **label field** or a **(pseudo)instruction** in statements like `db: db 'W'`, so it is mandatory in NASM but it may be optional in other assemblers. The way I chose in [€ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#SymbolName) is backward compatible with MASM/TASM/NASM - colon may be used  when the symbol is defined and referred but it is not required (unless it could be confused with a register or instruction name).

Comment: @vitsoft: It was an x86 instruction name as [Michael Petch] said in a comment. anyway, I thank you.

Comment: @LionKing: and this is why it's best to copy/paste things you've actually tested, especially when you don't understand why something does/doesn't work.  It was actually `str db ...` that wasn't working, not `msg db`.  Fuz is correct, `msg db ...` should always work.  But `str` is an x86 instruction mnemonic (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/).  Also best to include the exact error message.